# Как я могу убрать пробел из url в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, utf-8

проблема вот в чём: пользователь задаёт название своего поста и если вначале поста ставит пробел то ссылка на пост разваливается ибо в ней появляется %C2%A0 (utf символ неразрывного пробела). Как это убрать? 
Вот так сохраняю результат пользователя:

```
editor.save().then((outputData) => {
                let postParams = {};
                postParams.name = $("#name").text();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/post/add',
                    data: postParams,
                    success: function(data){
                        window.location.replace("/post/" + data);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: "ссылка на пост разваливается" - это какой-то новый технический термин? Не знаком с ним.

Comment: Пробелы из текстового поля убрать `postParams.name = $.trim($("#name").text())` перед отправкой на сохранение?

Comment: @Igor вот видите, век живи - век учись :))

Comment: @РустамГимранов Спасибо! Ваш вариант сработал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.replace(encodeURI("/post/" + data));
```

Или лучше

```
window.location.replace("/post/" + encodeURIComponent(data));
```

а то мало ли что еще они там напишут.

Comment: Работает. Чтобы железно было буду при записи использовать вариант @РустамГимранов и при сохранении - ваш. Спасибо :))